# Как указать заголовок Android сервиса (android:label для тега <service>) в AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, delphi, android-service, android-manifest, delphi-10-berlin

Создан проект в RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin (Delphi), в приложении прилинкован сервис.
При компиляции проекта в AndroidManifest.xml появляется строчка:

```
<service android:exported="true" android:name="com.embarcadero.services.MyService" />
```

А мне нужна строчка:

```
<service android:exported="true" android:name="com.embarcadero.services.MyService" android:label="Этот замечательный сервис создан вручную"/>
```

Ни где не нашел такое свойство. В *Project->Options->Version info* есть свойство *Label* только для самого Host приложения.

Помогите пожалуйста советом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашлось такое решение:

в файле host приложения *AndroidManifest.template.xml* необходимо строчку

```
<%services%>
```

заменить на

```
<service android:exported="true" android:name="com.embarcadero.services.MyService" android:label="Этот замечательный сервис создан вручную"/>
```

Если приложение включат несколько сервисов, необходимо таким образом указать их все.
После этого необходимо перекомпилировать и собрать заново проект.

В информации о сервисе теперь отображается содержимое свойства *label*, а не *name*.